# String deserialization and conversion to JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

After deserializing my string and converting it to JSON using the code below:

```
JSONObject returnValue = new JSONObject();
String toJson = null;

    try
    {
        Object otherObjectValue = SerializationUtils
                .deserialize(myBytesArray);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        toJson = gson.toJson(otherObjectValue);
        returnValue.put(key, toJson);
    }
```

some part of the JSON still has something like:

`{ "key":"ATTRIBUTE_LIST", "value":"{\"attributeContract\":[{\"scope\":\"sso\",\"name\":\"SAML_SUBJECT\",\"description\":\"Click to Edit\",\"required\":true}]}"}`

which means everything in:

`"{\"attributeContract\":[{\"scope\":\"sso\",\"name\":\"SAML_SUBJECT\",\"description\":\"Click to Edit\",\"required\":true}]}"`

is one string instead being another object with fields. Is there something I can do to sanitize by JSONObject to make it properly JSON?

Comment: What is `myBytesArray`? What is `SerializationUtils`?

Comment: If `otherObjectValue` is already a JSONObject, then you `toJson` it again, you'll get a json object as one string

Comment: @cricket_007 myBytesArray is a variable of type byte[] variableName. SerializationUtils is from apache commons. otherObjectValue is not a JSONObject

Comment: Show full json structure

Answer (score 0):

The `key` part is OK, means the whole String is JSON formatted.
For the `value` part, `/`shows that the value of `value` is JSON formatted already.

So you may "deserialize" the value of `value` again to retrieve an Object result. Or you may ask the creator of origin JSON, to serialize origin Object one time into JSON format.